# AJAX error: not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: javascript, json

This program runs well with phonegap server, but unable to run with other server or from the source i.e (file:///C:/Users/samsung%20pc/Desktop/arts/www/index_1_2.html)

When I run this program it gives me error :

1. Origin file: not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
2. XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.

What is wrong in this program. Any suggestion will be fine.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/spoken?i=meaning+of+google&appid=...",
    async: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {document.write(data);},onerror:function(e){document.write(e);}});});
```

Comment: Ajax calls doesn't work from file:// protocol! And refer here for [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10636611/1681154)

Comment: @SaurabhSharma check the code shared by OP

Comment: You can send a GET or POST request if you use HTTP. But it doesn't make sense if you read a file from your hard disc. That's why AJAX doesn't work under `file://`.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal Is there any relation between the Title and Your question?

Comment: Looks like you just need to allow cross-origin xhr requests. use open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir and let me know if it helps